# Python Win32print Job Status

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, printing

I have been trying to get the status of a print job using win32print in Python.

The status codes provided by win32print don't seem to match the status code for the job in question. I have tried it on different printers but always get the same results.

```
import win32print
import subprocess

printer_name = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()

print("Printer: %s" % (printer_name))

hPrinter = win32print.OpenPrinter(printer_name)

try:
    hJob = win32print.StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, ("test of raw data", None, "RAW"))
    try:
        f = open("test2.ps", "r")
        win32print.StartPagePrinter(hPrinter)
        win32print.WritePrinter(hPrinter, bytes(f.read(), "utf-8"))
        win32print.EndPagePrinter(hPrinter)
    finally:
        win32print.EndDocPrinter(hPrinter)
finally:
    print("Printing: %s" % (hJob))
    win32print.ClosePrinter(hPrinter)

hPrinter = win32print.OpenPrinter(printer_name)
past_status_code = -0
while True:
    try:
        job = win32print.GetJob(hPrinter, hJob, win32print.JOB_INFO_1)
    except:
        break
    status_code = job['Status']

    if (status_code != past_status_code):
        print("Job Status Code: %s" % (status_code))

    past_status_code = status_code

    if (job['Status'] == win32print.JOB_STATUS_BLOCKED_DEVQ):
        print("BLOCKED_DEVQ")

    if (job['Status'] == win32print.JOB_STATUS_DELETED):
        print("Deleted")

    if (job['Status'] == win32print.JOB_STATUS_DELETING):
        print("Deleting")

    if (job['Status'] == win32print.JOB_STATUS_ERROR):
        print("Error")

    if (job['Status'] == win32print.JOB_STATUS_OFFLINE):
        print("Offline")

    if (job['Status'] == win32print.JOB_STATUS_PAPEROUT):
        print("PaperOut")

    if (job['Status'] == win32print.JOB_STATUS_PAUSED):
        print("Paused")

    if (job['Status'] == win32print.JOB_STATUS_RESTART):
        print("Restart")

    if (job['Status'] == win32print.JOB_STATUS_USER_INTERVENTION):
        print("User intervention")

    if (job['Status'] == win32print.JOB_STATUS_SPOOLING):
        print("Spooling")

    if (job['Status'] == win32print.JOB_STATUS_PRINTING):
        print("Printing")

    if (job['Status'] == win32print.JOB_STATUS_PRINTED):
        print("Printed")

    if (job['Status'] == win32print.JOB_STATUS_COMPLETE):
        print("Complete")
```

After running the script above I always get the same results/ status codes I seem to get 8208 and then a 148.

What I'm tried to do is check when a job has completed.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @panofish No I did not. Still stuck on it to this day. Did you have any luck? I can't believe there not a unified cross platform print lib for python.

Comment: if the network printer has not been added to your client machine you will get 8208 status code.

Comment: what do you mean by "The status codes provided by win32print don't seem to match the status code for the job in question"?

Comment: Also, both 8208 and 148 are invalid job statuses. Are you sure these numbers are the values of `job['Status']`?

Answer (score 1):

You can start here:

This script allows you to see your printing job queue. You can customize it using the [Get Job documentation](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32print__GetJob_meth.html) if you want to see the information of a specific Job.

```
import time
import win32print

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def print_job_checker():
    """
    Prints out all jobs in the print queue every 5 seconds
    """
    jobs = [1]
    while jobs:
        jobs = []
        for p in win32print.EnumPrinters(win32print.PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL,
                                         None, 1):
            flags, desc, name, comment = p

            phandle = win32print.OpenPrinter(name)
            print_jobs = win32print.EnumJobs(phandle, 0, -1, 1)
            if print_jobs:
                jobs.extend(list(print_jobs))
            for job in print_jobs:
                print "printer name => " + name
                document = job["pDocument"]
                print "Document name => " + document
            win32print.ClosePrinter(phandle)

        time.sleep(5)
    print "No more jobs!"

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print_job_checker()
```

Script taken from [this post](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/12/19/pywin32-monitor-print-queue/)

Comment: Can I test, when certain document is just printed => save the name of a document to database? I'm interested in detecting when the document is printed and I wouldn't like to miss it. Because, when printing small document on "Microsoft Print to PDF" it's so fast, that I see only "No more jobs"

Answer (score 0):

The returned status is a bit mask, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-rprn/1625e9d9-29e4-48f4-b83d-3bd0fdaea787?redirectedfrom=MSDN) , for example . Multiple values ​​can be OR'ed, so your value of 8208(hex 0x00002010) indicates that the printer has (all) status.

- hex 0x00002000 = PRINTER_STATUS_WAITING
- hex 0x00000010 = PRINTER_STATUS_PAPER_OUT