# Print document name that is actually being printed to printer

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, printing

What I'm trying to achieve is to print a file with win32print, so that I can
inform the user about the job that is actually being printed.

It is sufficient to print the file name to standard output with `print` function.

I have this code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53765699/python-win32print-job-status) to illustrate the problem.

```
from win32 import win32print
import subprocess

printer_name = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()

print("Printer: %s" % (printer_name))

hPrinter = win32print.OpenPrinter(printer_name)

try:
    hJob = win32print.StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, ("test of raw data", None, "RAW"))
    try:
        f = open("test2.ps", "r")
        win32print.StartPagePrinter(hPrinter)
        win32print.WritePrinter(hPrinter, bytes(f.read(), "utf-8"))
        win32print.EndPagePrinter(hPrinter)
    finally:
        win32print.EndDocPrinter(hPrinter)
finally:
    print("Printing: %s" % (hJob))
    win32print.ClosePrinter(hPrinter)
```

How would you notify the user about what is being printed (detect starting new job)?

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-rprn/1625e9d9-29e4-48f4-b83d-3bd0fdaea787?redirectedfrom=MSDN) are the status codes.

e.g. 0x00000400 means the printer is printing . I can't find how to get job actually being printed.

Comment: Do you want to get the document name? You could first [`EnumJobs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/enumjobs), then check the `JOB_INFO_x.Status` if it is `JOB_STATUS_PRINTED` or `JOB_STATUS_PRINTING`, and the `JOB_INFO_x.pDocument` is the document name.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT Could you please write the code snippet to see the checking and notifying? For now, it would be enough to print a message in the command line, to see successive printing of all documents. Later (not part of this question), I would like to inform in the status bar or use some progress bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print the document name of the job which is in printing status.
You could try the following sample:

```
import win32print

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hPrinter= win32print.OpenPrinter(name)
    job_info_level = 1
    job_infos = win32print.EnumJobs(hPrinter, 0, -1, job_info_level)
    for job_info in job_infos:
        if (job_info['Status'] == win32print.JOB_STATUS_PRINTING)
            print("Printing "+job_info['pDocument'])
    win32print.ClosePrinter(hPrinter)\
```

UPDATE:

To get the document name when printing, you could use [`FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/findfirstprinterchangenotification) and [`FindNextPrinterChangeNotification`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/findnextprinterchangenotification).

Set the [`JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_DOCUMENT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/printer-notify-info-data#remarks) in `FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification`.
You could refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15752645/10611792)

Comment: And is it possible to write something like: while there are jobs to print: print document_name

Comment: Thank you, I will try the answer you link to as soon as I'm on Windows laptop, anyway it looks pretty large. For me would be sufficient to detect if the printer just printed a document and save_it_to_db() as printed.