# win32print printed empty pdf file

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi

I have the following code which should print pdf file with a text, but it
printed empty pdf file. Do you know how to fix it?

```
from win32 import win32print


if __name__ == "__main__":

    printer_name = "Microsoft Print to PDF"

    print("Printer: %s" % (printer_name))

    hPrinter = win32print.OpenPrinter(printer_name)

    try:
        hJob = win32print.StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, ("test.pdf", None, "RAW"))
        try:
            f = open("to_print\\document1.pdf", "rb")
            win32print.StartPagePrinter(hPrinter)
            win32print.WritePrinter(hPrinter, f.read())
            win32print.EndPagePrinter(hPrinter)
            f.close()
        finally:
            win32print.EndDocPrinter(hPrinter)
    finally:
        print("Printing: %s" % (hJob))
        win32print.ClosePrinter(hPrinter)
```

If `ghostscript` is needed it is OK. But, I need to check for statuses of printing as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53765699/python-win32print-job-status)

Comment: What makes you think that your printer can print a raw PDF document?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Should I use rather TEXT? I'm on Linux now, I can test it on monday.

Comment: You've asked a series of questions on this subject now, but you don't seem to be getting the hint. So far as I know you need a program that can display PDF in order to print it. Probably something like Ghostscript. Printers, by and large, don't know how to render PDF. And what about file formats other than PDF?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan My input is a pdf file. If it will change in the future I don't know, so far.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I could use shellexecute according to [this](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html), but I need to check the status of the document, that's because I'm using win32print. I have seen projects on github that use pdf with win32print, so I adjusted my code to it.

Comment: I think you need to step back and learn a bit about how printers work.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan So, there is no possibility to put together win32print and some application that renders pdf (if win32print is not doing the rendering). If I understood you. I really need to check the statuses as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53765699/python-win32print-job-status)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that ghostscript can do this

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think, I've got it. I can use ghostscript and still check with win32print the job queue. I will try on monday. Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You have pseudo code which attempts to print PDF file to a PDF printer. If successful, the result will be the same PDF file. What is your actual goal?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani To print a pdf file on physical printer. Now, I'm testing on "Microsoft Print to PDF" to save paper.

Comment: Hi, have your issue been solved?

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT Hi, it is solved as a combination of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748386/how-to-catch-printer-event-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39249360/python-print-pdf-file-with-win32print/60573860?noredirect=1) questions answers. I will delete this.